# c# combine x amount of items from 2 lists into a 3'rd list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `List<T>`

```
List<T> listA = new List<T>();
List<T> listB = new List<T>();
```

each list contains a certain amount of items.

How can I can I create `List<List<T>>` that will contain 2 items from ListA and 4 items from ListB?

Example:

```
public class Item
{
     public string Category { get; set; }
}



List<Item> listA = new List<Item>();

//repeat the code bellow until listA will contain 8 items of category Apple (amount 8 is just an example)
listA.Add(new Item()
{
   Category = "Apple"
});


List<Item> listB = new List<Item>();

//repeat the code bellow until listB will contain 16 items of category Apple (amount 16 is just an example)
listB.Add(new Item()
{
   Category = "Pear"
});
```

So ListA contains 8 items of type Apple and ListB contains 16 items of type pear. I want to create individual `List<Item>` and each list to contains 2 items from ListA and 4 items from ListB so I will have 4 `List<Item>`.

```
List<Item> list1 // contains 2 items from ListA and 4 items from ListB
List<Item> list2 // contains 2 items from ListA and 4 items from ListB
List<Item> list3 // contains 2 items from ListA and 4 items from ListB
List<Item> list4 // contains 2 items from ListA and 4 items from ListB
```

now the 4 lists above can be added into a List

```
List<List<Item>> items = new List<List<Item>>();
items.Add(list1);
items.Add(list2);
items.Add(list3);
items.Add(list4);
```

Comment: How should two lists be transformed into a list of lists? Which list goes to the outer and which to the inner list? In other words: how do those lists rely on each other?

Comment: So the target list will contain two lists, one with the first 2 items in listA and the second with the first 4 items in listB?

Comment: I think you want new List<T> rather than List<List<T>>?

Comment: A [minimal example illustrating the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help

Comment: I made an edit with an example

Comment: You could use `.concat()` for concatenation of lists. And put concatenated sequances in a new list.

Comment: That edit made it even more confusing...

Comment: Check the update

Comment: Yes, it's getting better.

Comment: Based on your latest update, listA and listB are lists of different types. Do they share a common base class or interface?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: They are same type just some properties values are different

Comment: @musefan I was asking for clarifications. "apple" and "pear' are both of the same type, apple and pear are not. since the example given in the question clearly states apple and pear (and not "apple" and "pear"), I think my assumption is valid.

Comment: @user2818430: Please edit your question to add some sample code so that it will be more clear. Give us some sample data for listA and listB (a few items for each is enough). please make it clear if the types are different (as they seem to be based on your apples and pears explanation) and if so, do they share a common base or interface.

Comment: @musefan How is it my fault if the analogy is wrong? apples and pears are different things. you can't put an apple in a list<pear>, but you can put it in a list<fruit>.  A better analogy would be 2 huge bags, one with red apples and the other with green apples.

Comment: @musefan: How come you have that much rep and you don't understand that this is not just a take(x) solution?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I made an edit with an example.

Comment: @musefan "If I have 2 huge bags one with apples and one with pears." but this is a futile discussion. the last edit to the question finally made it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core problem here is the segmentation (making the groups of 2 and 4 items) for which you will need MoreLinq. After that it's a simple .Zip() of lists.

```
using System.Linq;
using MoreLinq;

var segA   = listA.Segment((x, i) => i % 2 == 0);
var segB   = listB.Segment((x, i) => i % 4 == 0);
var result = segA.Zip(segB, (a, b) => a.Concat(b).ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: @musefan: Yes it does and I think this works, testing it now. Didn't know about MoreLinq

Comment: @musefan: Sometimes things are obvious

Comment: @musefan: Yes I didn't knew about MoreLinq, but at least when I see an unfamiliar namespace I assume Nuget package by default. And I turned up to stackoverflow after few trials myself but I couldn't figure it out. If it was so obvious the solution for you why didn't you post an answer or advise? It seams you are mister perfect, pissing off people for not stating the obvious..

Answer (score 3):

To the original question,

> How can I can I create `List<List<T>>` that will contain 2 items from ListA and 4 items from ListB?

```
var result = new List<List<T>> { listA.Take(2).ToList(), listB.Take(4).ToList() };
```

Comment: I was going to post the exact same thing, pending a clarification from the OP. I wonder why it was downvoted.

Comment: Why is it 'clearly' wrong? It does answer the original question exactly.

Comment: @musefan when it was downvoted it was an exact answer to the question. edits made after it was downvoted makes it less appropriate.

Comment: @musefan I upvoted and wrote my original comment when it was correct (IMHO). If it's incorrect now is still yet to be determined, since the question is still not exactly clear. btw, This is why I didn't post my original though - because guessing answers for half-backed questions usually turns out wrong...

Comment: @musefan yet to be determined since the question is still not clear. My upvote can't be changed now unless the answer is edited. I will not edit someone else's answer just to retract my upvote.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider deleting this answer? After all you now know it isn't correct and it's just sitting here confusing the upvote sheep

Answer (score 1):

you would need something like this based on what i understood from your question.
As for the "condition" mentioned below, that you will have to figure out based on the cases you have.
one case could be: if it so happens that after making pairs, if 1 apple remains and 3 pears remain, what should be done.

```
public class AB()
{
    public List<T> AList { get; set; }
    public List<T> BList { get; set; }
}

//code in the function
List<AB> lstAB = new List<AB>();
int takeA = 2;
int takeB = 4;
int skipA = 0;
int skipB = 0;
while(condition)
{
    lstAb.Add(new AB() 
    { 
        AList = listA.Skip(skipA).Take(takeA).ToList(), 
        BList = listB.Skip(skipB).Take(takeB).ToList()
    });

    skipA += takeA;
    skipB += takeB;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to achieve there is no LINQ 'out of the box' method. 
You could use 3rd party libraries.

Or write your own extensions method:

```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static List<List<TEntity>> ToFixedSizeGroups<TEntity>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> list1, IEnumerable<TEntity> list2, int take1, int take2)
        {
            // check if the collection is a list already
            var list1Enumerated = list1 as IList<TEntity> ?? list1.ToList();
            var list2Enumerated = list2 as IList<TEntity> ?? list2.ToList();

            // If we want to use a single for loop we need to know max-length
            var longerList = list1Enumerated.Count > list2Enumerated.Count ? list1Enumerated : list2Enumerated;
            var grouppedList1 = Enumerable.Range(0, list1Enumerated.Count / take1).Select(x => new List<TEntity>()).ToList();
            var grouppedList2 = Enumerable.Range(0, list2Enumerated.Count / take2).Select(x => new List<TEntity>()).ToList();

            for (var i = 0; i < longerList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i < list1Enumerated.Count && i / take1 < grouppedList1.Count)
                {
                    grouppedList1[i / take1].Add(list1Enumerated[i]);
                }
                if (i < list2Enumerated.Count && i / take2 < grouppedList2.Count)
                {
                    grouppedList2[i / take2].Add(list2Enumerated[i]);
                }
            }

            return grouppedList1.Where(x => x.Count == take1).Zip(grouppedList2.Where(x => x.Count == take2), (x, y) => x.Concat(y).ToList()).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Example of use:

```
List<string> a = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three", "one"};
List<string> b = new List<string> { "four", "five", "four", "five" };

List<List<string>> groups = a.ToFixedSizeGroups(b, 3, 2);
```

Comment: I ended up using MoreLinq, but nice solution!